# How to load keras model with tensorflow v1.x backend in keras with tensorflow v2.x backend?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a saved model with `h5` format created using `keras` with `tensorflow v1.x` backend. I can no longer load this model in `keras` with `tensorflow v2.x` backend using `keras.models.load_model`. Is there anyway to migrate the saved model to make it compatible with newer `keras` with `tensorflow v2.x` backend?

So far I have found tools / tutorials to migrate the code but I could not find any useful way to upgrade the saved models. I know there is `tf.compat.v1.saved_model.load` method for tensorflow but I cannot really use that as I saved the model using `keras`.

Comment: What happens when you load the model using keras and tf 2.x? Do you get errors?

Comment: I had similar problems as you described. The best solution that I found is to load the weights in tf1+keras, and create a lut whose key is a layer name and whose value is the corresponding weights. Recreate the same model in tf2, and manually assign these weights. It will take you 5-10mins to convert 1 model, but if this is all you care, I think the time worths it.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Yes, I get the following error: https://pastebin.com/NAkQbSvn

Comment: Seems you are using a version of Keras that is not compatible with TensorFlow 2.0, you should use Keras 2.3.1

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro can you kindly write this into an answer so that I can accept it as solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to load the same model in TensorFlow 1.x and 2.x, but for this you need to use a version of Keras that supports both, for example, Keras 2.3.1